# .htaccess rewrite engine with cloduflare

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cloudflare

I added cloudflare to my domain and after that I can't get my code in .htaccess work. I had code that deleted extensions. **Example: *site.com/link.html --> site.com/link***

This is the code from .htaccess

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

# Start CloudFlare:tramvaj.info rewrite. Do not Edit 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.info 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] 
# End CloudFlare rewrite. 

RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: What is not working in this?

Comment: The thing if I open the page by clicking on link on my page it will add .html extension. Now I can open some page like this: mypage.com/link but when I go to lets say link2 it will do this: mysite.com/link2.html

Comment: Have you tried this in a new browser?

Comment: yes, and different versions of browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok can you try this:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

# Start CloudFlare:tramvaj.info rewrite. Do not Edit 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.info 
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE] 
# End CloudFlare rewrite. 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```